# how do I align text and image in same button

Tags: android

How do I align text and image with same button? I want to do like this image:

[image]

but my button looks like this, with text overlapping the image:

[image]

This is my code below. How do I make space in between text and image in the same button?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Button android:id="@+id/btnUtilitybillpayments"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/handshake"
            android:layout_marginRight="55dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
            android:drawablePadding="-25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:text="Utility Bills Payment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is occurred because you are giving android:layout_marginRight="55dip".

Comment: either remove `android:layout_marginRight="55dip"` or minimize Margin from Right Side `android:layout_marginRight="15dip"`

Comment: if you are using static texts then alternatively you can have image with predefined text so in that case you don't need to align text

Answer (score 1):

I think you made your button to Complex,

Just use below code and let me know what happen..

```
<Button   android:id="@+id/btnUtilitybillpayments"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginRight="55dip"
             android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/handshake"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
             android:gravity="left"
             android:paddingLeft="20dip"
             android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
             android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
             android:text="Utility Bills Payment"/>
```

As I have also doubt on layout_margin attributes of your Button. If it doesn't work then try to remove

```
 android:layout_marginRight="55dip"
 android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
```

Comment: ur code remove space in left side of image see this   http://imgur.com/oFwZ2    only make space in between image and tet but left side of space from image is remove

Comment: Also you will like to set the gravity of button else text will come in center and drawable in extrema left.

Comment: Now put `android:drawablePadding="20dip"` or  `android:paddingLeft="20dip"`.

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'drawablePaddingLeft' in package 'android'

Comment: ur code is work for only 1 buttto if two button with diffent text is show diffrent alligment  see like this  http://imgur.com/EFGAY

Comment: Also try with `android:gravity="left"`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
 android:text="Drawable left">
Button>

For more info go to this link
```

http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/8/Creating-Android-button-with-image-and-text-using-relative-layout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUtilitybillpayments"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/handshake"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Utility Bills Payment"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />
```

Comment: yea so gravity makes the content inside the button arrange accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A more suitable approach is by making the button as a 9patch image. That way, you can define where the text should be by patching the right and bottom side. And there wont be any need for such complex button.

You can go here for more information-

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html